# Thumbnail image do not display in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image

I have written a basic code that gets the image stored in the image folder creates a thumbnail for that image and saves in another folder called 'thumbnail' and then later this thumbnail image is displayed.
'image' gets the required image from folder whose thumbnail is required.
'imagename' is the string that saves the name of image.
'imgThumb' is the thumb image saved in thumbnails folder.

```
imagename = dt.Rows[0]["image"].ToString();
                System.Drawing.Image imgThumb = null;
                System.Drawing.Image image = null;
                image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("images/catalog/" + imagename ));

                if (image != null)
                {
                    imgThumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(50, 50, null, new IntPtr());
                    imgThumb.Save(MapPath("~/images/thumbnails/") + imagename );
                    Image.ImageUrl = "~/images/thumbnails/" + lnkimgnm;                      

                }
```

This code works fine locally. I can view the thumbnail image as required.
But same code when i uploaded on the server its not working.I mean i cant see the thumbnail of the image.May be that its not getting the image itself to generate the thumbnail. What could be the difference?

I tried assigning the url of an existing thumbnail image than it was displaying.It means that either its not getting the image from images/catalog folder or it cannot save the thumbnail at the specified path.

Please need help. Note: this code is working fine locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see, if you can save and view thumbnails offline perfectly and if it is not workin online only then you can try few things online

1. check your folder/vertual directory properties. give that folder read and write permission.
2. check folder spelling.

Comment: Yes folder did not had read write permission. Thanks alot!! had stucked for long time